# can't get new value of previously updated element in a loop

Tags: dataweave

I have an array of objects.

```
     [
      {
        "b": 0,
        "a": 5
      },
      {
        "b": 0,
        "a": 10
      },
      {
        "b": 0,
        "a": 15
      }
    ]
```

Now I want to change every `b` field to sum of previous object's `a` and `b` values.

When I use map function I skip first element because there is no element before it, then I do some calculation on every element. For example on this element: `{"a":10,"b":0}`, `b` will be updated to 5 (because in previous object `a` is 5 and `b` is 0. So sum is 5).
Next, for the 3rd object (which is: `{"a":15,"b":0})`, `b` should be updated to 15. Because in the previous iteration, I have updated the value of `b` to 5.

My problem is DataWeave map function is taking the old value of `b` instead of updated one. So it's producing below output:

```
    [
      {
        "b": 0,
        "a": 5
      },
      {
        "b": 5,
        "a": 10
      },
      {
        "b": 10,
        "a": 15
      }
    ]
```

Instead I'm expecting this output:

```
    [
      {
        "b": 0,
        "a": 5
      },
      {
        "b": 5,
        "a": 10
      },
      {
        "b": 15,
        "a": 15
      }
    ]
```

Here is my script:

```
    %dw 2.0
    output application/json
    ---
    payload map ((item, index) -> {
        b: if (index == 0) 0 else (payload[index - 1].a + payload[index - 1].b),
        a: item.a
    })
```

I don't know how to get the updated value in every iteration. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below solution.

In this code, we use reduce to iterate through the array and accumulate the result. The accumulator acc has two properties: b and arr. b holds the current value of b, and arr holds the array of objects we are constructing.

Inside the reduce function, we update b based on the previous value of b and the previous a value from the array. Then, we add a new object to the arr array that contains the new value of b and the current a value.

Finally, we return the arr property of the accumulator, which contains the array of objects we constructed.

Input

```
[
  {
    "b": 0,
    "a": 5
  },
  {
    "b": 0,
    "a": 10
  },
  {
    "b": 0,
    "a": 15
  }
]
```

Dataweave Script

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(payload reduce ((item, acc={b: 0, arr: []}) -> {
    b: if (isEmpty(acc.arr)) 0 else acc.b + acc.arr[-1].a,
    a: item.a,
    arr: acc.arr ++ [{ b: if (isEmpty(acc.arr)) 0 else acc.b + acc.arr[-1].a, a: item.a }]
})).arr
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "b": 0,
    "a": 5
  },
  {
    "b": 5,
    "a": 10
  },
  {
    "b": 15,
    "a": 15
  }
]
```

Comment: Please, explain your solution instead of just giving the code.

Comment: I tried to explain it. I have edited my answer with the explanation. I hope that helps